# Python custom log to database

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark

I have the following sample Python code, and when I try to execute, am getting mysql error message.  Context, am trying to create custom logs, log the messages, insert to a MySql table for analysis.  Providing relevant portions for mysql execute.

```
levelnum= str(record.levelno) # 40
levelname=str(record.levelname) # ERROR
msg=str(self.log_msg)   # "This error occurred: This is test message"
createtime=str(tm)  #2018-06-26 03:43:47
record.name = 'MY_LOGGER'

sql = 'INSERT INTO emp.log (log_level, log_levelname, log, created_at, created_by) VALUES ('+levelnum+ ', '+levelname+ ', '+msg+ ', '+createtime+ ', '+record.name+')'

Error message: ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'error msg, 2018-06-26 03:43:47, MY_LOGGER)' at line 1")
```

Am using mysql, and trying to insert to the table as follows:

```
try:
   self.sql_cursor.execute(sql)
   self.sql_conn.commit()
 except pymysql.InternalError as e:
   print e
   print 'CRITICAL DB ERROR! Logging to database not possible!'
```

I think, am missing some formatting while passing parameters in the SQL query, but couldn't get the correct one.

Appreciate if someone can help fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not quoting the timestamp, hence the error.

Rather than trying to quote the values manually, use the built-in quoting functionality provided by pymysql as part of the DBI interface.

```
    sql = 'INSERT INTO `emp.log` (`log_level`, `log_levelname`, `log`, `created_at`, `created_by`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'

    self.cursor.execute(sql, (levelnum, levelname, msg, createtime, record.name))
```